# bullet lists not rendering in blogdown .rmd file

Tags: html, r, blogdown, bullet

Bullet points will not render when I serve my site in blogdown.  My site is hosted locally on my Windows 10 machine.  When I add html tags, the list actually works.  Bullet points render correctly when I open a blank rmd file in another project.

Example of my list code in the blogdown .rmd post:

```
* text
* text
* text
```

And the working version using html tags:

```
<ul>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

```
>sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
Matrix products: default
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.0       bookdown_0.9     digest_0.6.18    later_0.8.0      mime_0.6         R6_2.4.0         jsonlite_1.6     magrittr_1.5    
 [9] evaluate_0.13    blogdown_0.11    stringi_1.3.1    rstudioapi_0.9.0 promises_1.0.1   rmarkdown_1.11   tools_3.5.2      servr_0.13      
[17] stringr_1.4.0    httpuv_1.4.5.1   xfun_0.5         yaml_2.2.0       compiler_3.5.2   htmltools_0.3.6  knitr_1.22
```

This is my first question asked on Stack Overflow.  I did a lot of searching beforehand but please point me in the right direction if I missed the answer!

I'm also experiencing an issue where using the 'add image' addin does not work.  I don't know if they're related, but can post additional code snippets if it is relevant.

Better example below:

```
---
title: "Methodology and link to BidVis"
author: "Braden"
date: '2019-03-14'
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
categories: []
slug: methodology-and-link-to-bidvis
tags: []
bibliography: []
---
```

### Introduction

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(kableExtra)
  options(kableExtra.auto_format = FALSE)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(rio)
  install_formats()
library(ggrepel)
library(janitor)
library(lubridate)
library(broom)
library(generics)
library(plotly)
library(DT)

In speaking with my classmates and from my own experience, I sought to use the data to answer the following questions:
* How can I predict closing cost for an upcoming class?
* What is the relationship between TCE scores and course closing cost?
* What are the most powerful indicators of a class having a high closing cost?
* Is the "bid point inflation" effect real?

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you show us the attempt using the markdown version in the actual code? Many of these issues involve problems with indentation and formatting

Comment: I've done so, let me know if I should add anything else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add an empty line before the list:

```
In speaking with my classmates and from my own experience, I sought to use the data to answer the following questions:  

* How can I predict closing cost for an upcoming class?
* What is the relationship between TCE scores and course closing cost?
* What are the most powerful indicators of a class having a high closing cost?
* Is the "bid point inflation" effect real?
```

Comment: Are the two spaces at the end of each line necessary? In Stack Overflow markdown, only the empty lines before and after are needed.

Comment: in my experience it depends on what tools you are using to render the document. The two spaces can indicate the end of a line whereas a single space allows you to continue writing that line on the next line of your editor. In the version of RStudio I am using the two spaces are not required, but there are some environments that require the explicit end of line.

Comment: The empty line before the list is necessary, but the two spaces should not be.

Comment: I have removed the 2 spaces from my answer. Thanks @YihuiXie!